# How can we add label to react phone input 2

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, label, styles, textfield

I am using react-phone-input-2.
For other inputs i am using material ui textfield with label.
Is it possible to add label for react phone input like material ui with variant outlined.

```
 <PhoneInput
   inputProps={{
    name:'phone',
    required:true,
    autoFocus:true
```

}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this link and add the material css file

```
https://bl00mber.github.io/react-phone-input-2-css.html
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a custom label in react-phone-2 by passing props to the input box as like that:

```
<PhoneInput
  {...props}
  specialLabel="Custom Phone*"
/>
```

For more reference visit
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-input-2#other-props